# Change password error

Tags: asp.net, membership, change-password

I want to change a password for a user.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(ddlUsers.SelectedValue, false);
**mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), "password2!");**
```

This is my Error:
Value can not be null. Parameter name: password answer

Anyone a idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `web.config` you probably have a value that requires you to set a security question/answer for a member. You can turn this off with this setting in your membership provider settings section in your `web.config`:

```
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

Comment: This was also 1 of my folds.
The machine configuration specifies a SqlMembershipProvider instance named **"AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"** that is identified as the default provider if you do not specify a default provider explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Default provider name ="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"

Web.config:

```
<membership>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <!-- Default provider name--> <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="6" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="8"
               />
          </providers>
        </membership>
```